# All connections lost when connecting to OpenVPN server

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

What I have:

- OSX/PC
- VDS (ubuntu server)
- VPN provider account

What I did:

- Installed `openvpn` on VDS.
- Successfully connected from PC to VDS server.
- Successfully connected from VDS to VPN provider with my login/password.
- Lost all connections.

Why did this happen? What should I do? I read something about routes and iptable rules, but I can't make sense of it.

Here are my confs:

PC/OSX `client.conf`:

```
client
dev tun1
proto udp
remote VDS_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP 1194
resolv-retry infinite
remote-random
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
ping 15
ping-restart 0
ping-timer-rem
reneg-sec 0
ca ./ca.crt
cert ./client01.crt
key ./client01.key

remote-cert-tls server
```

VDS `server.conf`:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun1
tls-server
;server 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0
server 10.8.8.0 255.255.255.0
client-to-client
max-clients 10
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
push redirect-gateway
push route 192.168.0.0 255.255.155.0
duplicate-cn
ca /etc/openvpn/keys1/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys1/server1.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys1/server1.key
dh /etc/openvpn/keys1/dh2048.pem
```

VDS `client.conf`:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote VPN_PROVIDER_PUBLIC_IP 1194
resolv-retry infinite
remote-random
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
ping 15
ping-restart 0
ping-timer-rem
reneg-sec 0

remote-cert-tls server

#mute 10000
auth-user-pass

comp-lzo
verb 3
pull
fast-io
cipher AES-256-CBC

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
qwe
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
qwe
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

Comment: You are pushing `redirect-gateway` to your client which will break all your current non-local connections